# javax.mail hangup - When specifying a valid ip, other than an SMTP server

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to create a mail sending util in java. It works fine when using a valid SMTP server as host. The issue is whenever someone specifies a valid IP other than SMTP server, it hangsup. How to resolve this issue? Is there a way set timeout in javax.mail other than using threads?

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share the code you have tried first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`mail.smtp.connectiontimeout`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.connectiontimeout) property.